# mmap vs. malloc: strange performance

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, memory, d

I'm writing some code that parses log files, with the caveat that these files are compressed and must be uncompressed on the fly. This code a somewhat performance sensitive piece of code so I'm trying various methods to find the right one. I have essentially as much RAM as the program will ever need, no matter how many threads I'm using.

I've found a method that seems to perform quite well, and I'm trying to understand why it offers better performance.

Both methods have a reader thread, one which reads from a piped gzip process and writes to a large buffer. This buffer is then lazily parsed when the the next log line is requested, returning what is essentially a struct of pointers to where the different fields live in the buffer.

Code is in D, but it's very similar to C or C++.

Shared variable:

```
shared(bool) _stream_empty = false;;
shared(ulong) upper_bound = 0;
shared(ulong) curr_index = 0;
```

Parsing code:

```
//Lazily parse the buffer
void construct_next_elem() {

    while(1) {
        // Spin to stop us from getting ahead of the reader thread
        buffer_empty = curr_index >= upper_bound -1 &&
                       _stream_empty;
        if(curr_index >= upper_bound && !_stream_empty) {
            continue;
        }
        // Parsing logic .....
    }
}
```

Method 1:
Malloc a buffer large enough to hold the unzipped file in up front.

```
char[] buffer;                   // Same as vector<char> in C++
buffer.length = buffer_length;   // Same as vector reserve in C++ or malloc
```

Method 2:
Use an anonymous memory map as a buffer

```
MmFile buffer;
buffer = new MmFile(null,
                    MmFile.Mode.readWrite, // PROT_READ || PROT_WRITE
                    buffer_length,
                    null);                 // MAP_ANON || MAP_PRIVATE
```

Reader thread:

```
ulong buffer_length = get_gzip_length(file_path);
pipe = pipeProcess(["gunzip", "-c", file_path],
                                   Redirect.stdout);
stream = pipe.stdout();

static void stream_data() {
    while(!l.stream.eof()) {

        // Splice is a reference inside the buffer
        char[] splice = buffer[upper_bound..upper_bound + READ_SIZE];
        ulong read = stream.rawRead(splice).length;
        upper_bound += read;
    }
    // Clean up
}

void start_stream() {
        auto t = task!stream_data();
        t.executeInNewThread();
        construct_next_elem();
}
```

I'm getting significantly better performance out of method 1, even on the order of magnitude

```
User time (seconds): 112.22
System time (seconds): 38.56
Percent of CPU this job got: 151%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 1:39.40
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3784992
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 5463
Voluntary context switches: 90707
Involuntary context switches: 2838
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

vs.

```
User time (seconds): 275.92
System time (seconds): 73.92
Percent of CPU this job got: 117%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 4:58.73
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3777336
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 944779
Voluntary context switches: 89305
Involuntary context switches: 9836
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Getting way more page faults with Method 2.

Could someone help me shed light on why there's such a stark decrease in performance using mmap?

If anyone knows of any better ways to accomplish there problem, I would gladly hear it.

EDIT-----

Changed Method 2 to do:

```
       char * buffer = cast(char*)mmap(cast(void*)null,
                            buffer_length,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE,
                            -1,
                            0);
```

now getting a 3x performance increase over using a simple MmFile. I'm trying to figure out what could cause such a sharp different in performance what what it essentially just a wrapper around mmap.

Perf numbers for just using a straight char* mmap vs Mmfile, way way less page faults:

```
User time (seconds): 109.99
System time (seconds): 36.11
Percent of CPU this job got: 151%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 1:36.20
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3777896
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2771
Voluntary context switches: 90827
Involuntary context switches: 2999
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Comment: Well, nothing unexpected. `mmap()` causes the file to be `faulted in` chunk by schunk. The amount of I/O is the same in both cases, but it is performed at less desireable moments in the mmap() case.

Comment: and mmap uses opIndex (overloaded method), instead you can pull out the void[] for direct access by doing `buffer = mmap[];`

Comment: wildplasser, I'm directly writing to the mmap from a pipe before accessing it. So I'm a waiting on pages to load before I write to them vs. having them up front with malloc? I'm directly writing to the mmap from a pipe before I read from them, so I'd imagine those pages would be cached for a while.

Comment: Ah yes thanks ratchet, getting way better perf now that I'm using mmap() directly for core.sys.linux.sys.mman. Better than a malloced buffer.

Comment: You are **writing** to the mmap()d region? Does the file initially have contents? What would you *expect* to happen? BTW: is this the first time you ever use mmap()? do you really understand how virtual memory works? BTW2: I don't know `D` at all.

Comment: Yes. Did you even read the code? The file I'm reading is compressed. So I open a pipe to a decompression process, and reading data from that pipe INTO the mmap region, to be parsed later. As you can see in the code above the mmap is anonymous, I can't just mmap on the compressed files handle. Either way, the issue was with D's data copying and GC semantics being ambiguous in this situation.

Comment: Yes, I *tried* to read the code, but as I said, I don't know `D`. You realise that normally (at least on linux) `malloc()` et.al. are inplemented as anonymous mappings, causing `/dev/zero` to be COW-ed in ?

Comment: Yes, this is why I was confused about why the performance of using MmFile (D's wrapper for mmap) was so poor.

Comment: Am i the only one to think that `char[] buffer;` should actually be `ubyte[] buffer;` ? you could also call `malloc()` and `free()` directly since `buffer` is GC-managed.

Comment: Please use `ubyte` to hold 1 byte data instead of `char` as `char` signifies that the data is a valid UTF-8 code unit. Also, you will then be sure that no UTF decoding is attempted if you loop over the data or passed the buffer to an algorithm in `std.algorithm`.

Comment: Try to mmap it read-only. No point to let the kernel track all writes if you only are going to parse this file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting pagefaults and slow-downs because the mmap is by default only loading the page once you try to access it.

Read on the otherhand *knows* that you are reading sequentially, so it fetches pages ahead of time before you have asked for them.

Have a look at the [madvise](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) call -- it is intended to signal to the kernel how you are intending to access the mmap'ed file, and allow you to set different strategies for different parts of the mmap memory -- for example you have an index block you want to keep in memory [MADV_WILLNEED], but the content is accessed randomly and on demand[MADV_RANDOM], or you are looping though the memory in a sequential scan [MADV_SEQUENTIAL]

However the OS is entirely *free* to ignore the strategy you are setting, so YMMW

Comment: You probably want [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) not `posix_fadvise`

Comment: ... thanks for the correction, yes use `madvise` -- I should have looked at my sourcecode before writing the answer :)